# Google maps not display about new version with xcode8.2

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, swift3

I try to use the Google Maps SDK for iOS with the Swift and Xcode 8.2.

I had set the API Key correct.

I using the Google Map SDK website sample code.

```
   let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(-33.86,
                                                      longitude: 151.20, zoom: 6)
    let mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera: camera)
    mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
    myView = mapView
```

It will show the errors:

> 'cameraWithLatitude(_:longitude:zoom:)' has been renamed to 'camera(withLatitude:longitude:zoom:)'
>
> swift:84:47: 'CGRectZero' is unavailable in Swift
>
> swift:85:17: 'myLocationEnabled' has been renamed to 'isMyLocationEnabled'

So I change the to like below:

```
   let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: -33.86,
                                                      longitude: 151.20, zoom: 6)
    let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
    myView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
    myView = mapView
```

But the google map is still not display.

Have anyone known where is the problem?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you have initialized `mapView` with `CGRect.zero` so the frame is `(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)` means `0 width` and `0 height`, instead of that set the `frame` properly like your `view.bounds`.

```
let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: self.view.bounds, camera: camera)
```

Comment: @dickfala Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 0):

Have your Enable API at [API Consol](https://console.developers.google.com)

[image]